# binding is used in WCF as a remoting alternative

Tags: wcf, remoting

If we want to replace remoting to WCF what biding is used ?
If we have used a shared dll beetwen two application in remoting to send message.
how this task can be done in WCF.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would depend on your infrastructure. If your services are all on the same machine, you could use `NetNamedPipeBinding`. If services and consumers are on different machines, you could use either `NetTcpBinding` or `BasicHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 1):

```
This solved my purpose... 

private const int RF_TESTMESSAGE = 0xA123;
        const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
        const int WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 0x0001;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Msg, IntPtr wParam, int lParam);

        public FormVideoApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblProcID.Text = string.Format("This process ID: {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        }     

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get this running process
            Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            //get all other (possible) running instances
            //Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc.ProcessName);
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Application");
            int numberToSend = 1500;
            string str = string.Empty;
            str = "start";
            switch (str)
            {
                case "start":
                    numberToSend = 101;
                    break;
                case "stop":
                    numberToSend = 102;
                    break;
                case "error":
                    numberToSend = 103;
                    break;
            }

            if (processes.Length > 0)
            {
                //iterate through all running target applications
                foreach (Process p in processes)
                {
                    if (p.Id != proc.Id)
                   {
                        //now send the RF_TESTMESSAGE to the running instance
                        //SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, RF_TESTMESSAGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                       SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, IntPtr.Zero, numberToSend);
                   }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No other running applications found.");
            }
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            //filter the RF_TESTMESSAGE
            if (message.Msg == WM_CUSTOM_MESSAGE)
            {
                int numberReceived = (int)message.LParam;
                string str=string.Empty;
                //Do ur job with this integer

                switch (numberReceived)
                {
                    case 101: str = "start";                       
                        break;
                    case 102: str = "stop";
                        break;
                    case 103: str = "error";
                        break;
                }
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(str + "Received message RF_TESTMESSAGE");
            }
            else
            {
                base.WndProc(ref message);
            }

            ////filter the RF_TESTMESSAGE
            //if (message.Msg == RF_TESTMESSAGE)
            //{
            //    //display that we recieved the message, of course we could do
            //    //something else more important here.
            //    this.listBox1.Items.Add("Received message RF_TESTMESSAGE");
            //}
            //be sure to pass along all messages to the base also
            //base.WndProc(ref message);
        }
```